# Business Letter in HTML

Tags: html, css

Here's my first effort at reformation: a business letter I wrote for a friend.  I would appreciate a review.  (Yes, I know this is a trivial example and it would be much more beneficial to have something reviewed that is more complicated.  But I want to nip bad practices in the bud now, before they become embedded in me.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .bodyBody {
                margin: 10px;
                font-size: 1.50em;
            }
            .divHeader {
                text-align: right;
                border: 1px solid;
            }
            .divReturnAddress {
                text-align: left;
                float: right;
            }
            .divSubject {
                clear: both;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding-top: 80px;
            }
            .divAdios {
                float: right;
                padding-top: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="bodyBody">
        <div class="divReturnAddress">
            Lopes de Almeido, Evanildo<br/>
            Bl&auml;siring 161 <br/>
            4057 Basel <br/>    
            <br/>
            01 Dezember, 2012
        </div>

        <div class="divSubject">
            Betreff:  Vertretung waehrend Reise
        </div>

        <div class="divContents">
            <p>
                Sehr geehrte Frau Graf,
            </p>

            <p>
                Ich fliege nach Brasilien am 29. Dezember 2012 f&uuml;r 6 Wochen.
                Meine Nichte kann mich vertreten.  Sie arbeitet sehr gesissenhaft.
                Sie heisst Yasmin.  Ihre Nummer ist xxx.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="divAdios">
            Freundliche Gr&uuml;sse <br/>
            <!-- Space for signature. -->
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            Evanildo Lopes do Almeida <br/>
            Hauswart Binningerstrasse 19/23 <br/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider using microformats, such as [hCard](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard), for appropriate data. This may make it more searchable.

Comment: Useful: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 6):

### CSS

Since this is a single document, not a webpage of a website, it's fine to use internal CSS in the `style` element instead of linking to an external stylesheet. However, if you plan to write more letters in the future, you should create a stylesheet that includes all the shared styles that are typical for a letter and link to it from each letter (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="letter.css" />`).

You could name your classes more meaningful, but this is only a good practice, not a requirement.

You could omit the class on `body`.

### Encoding/Charset

You should add the encoding to the document. If you want to use UTF-8 (recommended), add `<meta charset="utf-8" />` as the first child of the `head` element.

### `title` element

You are missing the `title` element, which is required. Add it as child of `head`: `<title>Vertretung während Reise – 1. Dezember 2012</title>`

### Return address

The use of `<br/>` is correct here. However, the date is not part of the address, and therefor it shouldn't be separated by `br`. Put the date in its own element instead. HTML5 offers the [`time` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-time-element.html#the-time-element).

Because this is your address (and not the recipient address), you should enclose it in the `address` element.

You could enclose the return address and the date in the [`header` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-header-element.html#the-header-element). It might also be possible to enclose the return address in a [`footer` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-footer-element.html#the-footer-element) and the `time` in a `header` (probably together with the `h1`), but this could be overkill ;)

### Subject line / Betreff

Instead of using a meaningless `div` for the subject, you should use `h1` here, as it is the heading of the whole document.

### Salution / Anrede

It's arguably if the salution is a paragraph on its own, or if it is part of the first paragraph. I think when followed by a comma, it should be part of the following paragraph. But this is not undisputed (I have no detailed knowledge about the semantics of a letter).

### Greets

The use of the `br` element to separate the greeting from your anme is correct here. But don't use *several* `br` elements just because you want to add more spacing. Use only one and apply a class to it, so that you can give it a higher vertical `margin` (CSS).

Also, include this in a `p` instead of a `div`.

---

### Example

So your letter could look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> <!-- first element so that the encoding is applied to the title etc. -->
    <title>Vertretung während Reise – 1. Dezember 2012</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="letter.css" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <header> 
      <address class="return-address">
        Lopes de Almeido, Evanildo<br/>
        Bläsiring 161 <br/>
        4057 Basel <br/>    
      </address>

      <time datetime="2012-12-01">01 Dezember, 2012</time>
    </header>

    <h1>
      Betreff:  Vertretung waehrend Reise
    </h1>

    <div class="content"> <!-- use this div only if it is required for styling -->
        <p>
          Sehr geehrte Frau Graf,
          <br class="salution" />

          Ich fliege nach Brasilien am 29. Dezember 2012 für 6 Wochen.
          Meine Nichte kann mich vertreten.  Sie arbeitet sehr gesissenhaft.
          Sie heisst Yasmin.  Ihre Nummer ist xxx.
        </p>
        <p>
          …
        </p>
      </div>

      <p class="adios">
        Freundliche Grüsse 
        <br class="greets" />
        Evanildo Lopes do Almeida <br/>
        Hauswart Binningerstrasse 19/23
      </p>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would the higher vertical margin for the `<br>` element be done like this `br.greets { margin: 100px; }` where 100px would be adjusted for the space I wanted?

Comment: @John: Yes. You could also use `.greets` as selector, so this style can be used even if you decide to use `p` instead of `br` in the future. And instead of `px` you could use the unit `em`, which always is in relation to the font-size of parents (so if you have a higher font-size, the margin gets higher, too).

Comment: For the `detailed semantics of a letter`, a good forum to consult might be http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ANeves: Or http://german.stackexchange.com in this case. I guess letter "conventions" differ by language (or more so, country).

Comment: I think using the time element for the date is a bit excessive. Possibly could use U+00DF in Binningerstrasse if using umlauts in Bläsiring  ?

Comment: @mckenzm: Why would that be "excessive"? It’s a date and HTML5 provides the `time` element for dates. // Regarding *Straße*: I ignored the actual content of the letter, as reviewing it would be off-topic here (but as a side note, in Swiss German both forms seem to be correct, *Straße* and *Strasse*).

Comment: Because it is always historical and cannot be used for future appointments. Compare the verbosity. Also for legal purposes you really want dates in business letters to appear as you write them, not as a reader/browser renders them.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, since you use HTML to write a business letter I assume you want to send an HTML e-mail? Since e-mail clients are [far away from adopting web standards](http://www.email-standards.org/) and require [special tactics](http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/), this might not be the best area to practise writing HTML. For example, you should separate your CSS from the HTML (as Ben suggests) but aren't able to do this in HTML E-Mail.

Now, focusing on your code, I can mainly echo what Ben writes (especially using `div.name` instead of `divName`, using the body-tag `body` instead of the selector `.bodyBody`).

Additionally, I would suggest you use utf-8 encoding, so you can type your German umlauts (ä,ö,ü) instead of `&auml;`. Do this by inserting this line right after your head (and actually saving in UTF-8 in your text editor!)

```
<head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Also, use `<br />` only when you actually want to have a line break. It is commonly abused as a 'quick and dirty' spacer, the better way would be, to use a `<p>` tag for your *Freundliche Grüße* and give it a margin, like so:

```
div.adios p {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

If you have several `<p>` you can select only the first child like this:

```
div.adios p:first-child {
```

Finally, I think I would wrap *.subject* into *.contents*, but that is just personal preference. Maybe, semantically, it would even make sense to just use the *h1* tag instead of *.subject* like so:

```
<div class="contents">
  <h1>Betreff: Vertretung während Reise</h1>
  <p>Sehr geehrte Frau Graf,</p>
  <p>Ich fliege am 29. Dezember 2012 für 6 Wochen nach Brasilien...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use external css file. Create style.css, put there all your css code and then link it in html file inside head tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

There is no need to prefix class with selectors name. It's not semantic and you're limiting yourself to use it only on that specific selector. Not literally but semantically.

If you have two words in class name, don't write it like this: myCustomClass, use dash instead: my-custom-class.

Read this guide for css, it's very good: https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-css
and this guide for html: https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-html